# Ensuring HTTPS and WWW is present in URL with PHP

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to figure exactly how to do this. I want to make sure that when someone visits mysite.com, they are going through https://www.mysite.com

So for any of these:

```
http://mysite.com
http://www.mysite.com
https://mysite.com
```

Should be changed to:

```
https://www.mysite.com
```

It also needs to work for all subdirectories and files.

So any of these:

```
http://mysite.com/about
http://www.mysite.com/page.php
```

Should be changed to:

```
https://www.mysite.com/about
https://www.mysite.com/page.php
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: What HTTP server are you using ? it would be better to do some form of redirect / rewrite there than on every single PHP page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running apache with mod_rewrite, you can use something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Other servers should have similar options.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the following code is included at the start of your pages:

```
if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) { //if not using https
    $server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    if ($server == 'mysite.com') {
        $server = 'www.' . $server;
    }
    header('Location: https://' . $server . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```